# QgisQuickOSMPlugin - server replied: Too Many Requests; Model Designer, OSM, api-server

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-modeler, overpass-api, quickosm

I am working on a QGis model that downloads OSM data via the overpass-api server.

The needs for the model have gradually increased, which is why the error "Too Many Request" now appears more frequently. However, this does not happen every time. I suspect that the server has limited capacity and reaches its limits depending on the number of requests.

My question is: **What exactly is overloading the server?** The number of objects that are downloaded or requested or the number of overall requests from different persons in this specific moment?

Do I have to **reduce** the size of the model in general or **specify** the request?

---

QGIS-Version: 3.22.14-Białowieża
QGIS-Codeversion: 4cde646c
Qt-Version: 5.15.3
Python-Version: 3.9.5
GDAL-Version: 3.6.1
GEOS-Version: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
PROJ-Version: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
PDAL-Version: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)

Error: Error transferring [https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:xml]](https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout:xml%5D) [timeout:300];%0A(%0A node%22highway%22%3D%22service%22;%0A way%22highway%22%3D%22service%22;%0A relation%22highway%22%3D%22service%22;%0A);%0A(._;%3E;);%0Aout body;&info=QgisQuickOSMPlugin - **server replied: Too Many Requests**
[image]
Fehler trat bei der Ausführung von Download file-private_road aus
Execution failed after 19.09 Sekunden

Comment: Maybe the documentation about the limits help https://dev.overpass-api.de/overpass-doc/en/preface/commons.html.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. 

429 Too Many Requests:
The 429 status code indicates that the user has sent too many
   requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting"). 
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4